# $\epsilon$ - $\delta$ proof for continuity of $ \lim_{x \to a} \sqrt{x}$ for $ a > 0 $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

I am currently undergoing a Calculus I course as an undergraduate. I was hoping to gain some guidance into whether the proof I have worked out for the continuity of a function $ f(x) = \sqrt{x} $ is robust enough or is missing out on certain details.

**Aim: Prove that the function $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is continuous at $a > 0$**.

*(1) Finding the value of f(a) for which f is defined*

The function $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is defined for values of $x \ge 0$. Given $a > 0$,

$$
f(a) = \sqrt{a} \\
\lim_{x \to a} \sqrt{x} = \sqrt{a}
$$

*(2) Showing that $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \sqrt{x}$ exists for every $a > 0$*.

Hence, given $\epsilon > 0$, we aim to find a proper $\delta > 0$ such that:

$$0 < |x - a| < \delta \Rightarrow |\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a}| < \epsilon$$

Factorizing $|x-a|$,

$$
|x-a| = |\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a}||\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{a}| < \delta \\
|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a}| < \frac{\delta}{|\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{a}|}
$$

Since $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{a}\ge 0$, it follows that $\frac{1}{|\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{a}|} < 1$. Hence,

$$
|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a}| < \frac{\delta}{|\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{a}|} < \delta
$$

Therefore, we take $\delta = \epsilon$.

*Proof:*

$$
0 < |x - a| < \delta \Rightarrow |\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a}| < \delta = \epsilon.
$$

Since $f(a) = \sqrt{a}$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to a} \sqrt{x} = \sqrt{a}$ for $a > 0$,

$$
\lim_{x \to a} \sqrt{x} = f(a)
$$

and thus the function $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is continuous at every a > 0.

Any feedback on gaps or loopholes in this proof would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:

There was a flaw in my logic, as kindly pointed out below. Since $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{a}$ may fall in the range of values $0 \le \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{a} \le 1$ the assertion that $\frac{1}{|\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{a}|}$ does not hold.

The appropriate logic should be:

$$
\frac{\delta}{|\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{a}|} < \frac{\delta}{|\sqrt{a}|}
$$

for x > 0.

Hence,

$$
|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a}| < \frac{\delta}{|\sqrt{a}|}
$$

We choose $\delta = \epsilon\sqrt{a}$.

Revised proof:

$$
0 < |x - a| < \delta \Rightarrow |\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{a}| < \epsilon\sqrt{a}(\sqrt{a}) = \epsilon
$$

Comment: Close. But $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{a} \geq 0$ does not imply $1/|\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{a}| < 1$.

Comment: RIGHT! Thank you! Must have messed up it up by assuming that $a \ge 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason why $\frac  {\delta} {\sqrt x+\sqrt a}$ should be less than $\delta$ so your proof is not valid.

Note that $\frac  {\delta} {\sqrt x+\sqrt a} < \frac {\delta} {\sqrt a}$ (for $x>0$) so it is enough to choose $\delta =\epsilon \sqrt a $

Comment: I realize my mistake. Thank you for the correction!

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be defined. We want to find such $\delta>0$ that suffices $\forall x\in (a-\delta,a+\delta), |f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon$.
So, we're looking for such $\delta$ that: $|\sqrt x-\sqrt a|<\varepsilon$.
Notice: $|\sqrt x-\sqrt a|=\frac{|x-a|}{\sqrt x + \sqrt a}<\frac{|x-a|}{\sqrt a}<\frac{\delta}{\sqrt a}$.

Now let's define $\delta = \varepsilon \sqrt a$.

Therefore: $|\sqrt x-\sqrt a|=\frac{|x-a|}{\sqrt x + \sqrt a}<\frac{|x-a|}{\sqrt a}<\frac{\delta}{\sqrt a}=\frac{\varepsilon \sqrt a}{\sqrt a}=\varepsilon$.

** Notice that $\sqrt x, \sqrt a>0$ so the expression $\sqrt x + \sqrt a $ doesn't need absolute value.